Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native:packages:react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes'
Everytime I run pnpm start:android:dev it returns me the following error `
What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task 
>':react-native:packages:react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes'. 
>Could not create task ':react-native:packages:react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:installCMake'. 
> Could not find sdkmanager executable.

the detailed version of the error is here https://scans.gradle.com/s/bvstpyuewxyve/console-log?anchor=99&page=1
Assuming the problem is happening because of the sdkmanager wasn't installed properly so I tried to use the SDK from both command line tools only and android studio, I set the environment variables like this
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\hmeli\Downloads\android_sdk, then Path=%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\cmdline-tools\tools\bin still not working, I also tried writing the full path for platform-tools and sdkmanager instead of using %ANDROID_HOME% but it didn't help. In both case running the sdkmanager --version command works in command prompts and powershell but not in git bash.
How do I solve this problem?


I need to either update it or install a previous version. Going from there it worked.
Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or select SDK Manager from the toolbar to launch the SDK Manager from Android Studio. You can use the sdkmanager command-line tool to get tools if you're not using Android Studio.
The following URL should be checked: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

